# Bug in use of slice() has no effect?

Tags: javascript, slice

I noticed that the correct

```
return str.slice(0, res);
```

returns the same value as the incorrect

```
var str = "some_string";
return str.slice(str, res);
```

In this case `str` is a string and `res` is a numeric quantity.

My guess is that some how because slice expects a numeric quantity and does not get one ( for the first parameter ), it converts what it finds to a 0.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Lets have a look: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.10. Yes, it is expected, if `str` cannot be converted to a value different from `NaN`. See http://es5.github.io/#x9.4.

Comment: Looking at the annotation that @Felix linked to, note 5. "Let relativeStart be ToInteger(start)."

Comment: I posted the wrong like (arrays instead of strings), but both behave the same in this regard.

Comment: Do you consider the one-character string `5` (as opposed to the integer `5`) to be a "numeric quantity"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess is that some how because slice expects a numeric quantity and does not get one ( for the first parameter ), it converts what it finds to a 0.

That's [basically what happens](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.13). `.slice` calls [`ToInteger`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.4) on the first argument, which in turn calls [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3). But if the value cannot be converted to a number (if the result is `NaN`), it returns `0`.

So, if you pass a numeric string as start, `.slice` would start at the mathematical value of that string. Any other string converts to `0`.

Comment: Thanks, I always went to MDN to learn more about JS methods, but the ES spec is better it seems.

Comment: Yeah, MDN is good to get an idea about what is available and how to use it, but if you want an in-depth explanation of why things work the way they do, you have to go to the spec.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript provides implicit type coercion. That means if an integer is expected (as is the case here), it will [convert](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.13) the value provided to an integer. If no sensible value can be divined, zero is used.

If an integer is provided, great!

If a string is provided and it looks like a integer (e.g. `str.slice("5", res)`) it will be converted into the expected integer.

If a string is provided and it doesn't look like a number (e.g. `str.slice("abc", res)`), `0` is used.